# Is there a way to dump the individual arguments of va_list in windbg?

Tags: windbg

Is there a way to dump the arguments in va_list in windbg given the format string and the starting address of va_list?

Answer (score 0):

I usually do this by just dumping the content of the stack using command `dd esp` (for x86) or `dq rsp` (for x64). Knowing the starting address of va_list makes it a bit easier to locate the place in the stack where vararg block begins, but usually you can either guess it or calculate by knowing the sizes of regular (non-vararg parameters) to the function.

Here is an annotated example for x86. The function beeing called:

```
printf("%d %o %g %s %c", 101, 201, 301.0, "401-string", '5');
```

in debugger:

```
0:000> bp MSVCR100D!printf
0:000> g
Breakpoint 1 hit
eax=00000001 ebx=00000000 ecx=2549afc4 edx=00000000 esi=002ceeb8 edi=002cf040
eip=0ff57ee0 esp=002cee98 ebp=002cf04c iopl=0         nv up ei pl nz ac po nc
cs=0023  ss=002b  ds=002b  es=002b  fs=0053  gs=002b             efl=00000212
MSVCR100D!printf:
0ff57ee0 8bff            mov     edi,edi
0:000> dd /c1 esp
002cee98  01365cee  // return address
002cee9c  0137d6e8  // pointer to the format string "%d %o %g %s %c" --> next follows our variable arguments
002ceea0  00000065  // first vararg argument, int 101
002ceea4  000000c9  // second vararg argument, int 201
002ceea8  00000000  // third vararg argument, double 301.0, it occupies two slots in stack
002ceeac  4072d000  // third argument continues
002ceeb0  0137d70c  // fourth vararg argument, pointer to string
002ceeb4  00000035  // fifth vararg argument, 8-bit character (still occupies 4 bytes in stack)
002ceeb8  25b87244
002ceebc  002cf254
002ceec0  0041c520
002ceec4  00000000
...
```

For other functions it will be very similar, because all functions that use variable number of arguments have to be following __cdecl calling convention, so you will find the same type of layout of parameters in the stack.